# Allow user to access SQL using ado.net windows authentication but restrict them using SSMS

Tags: windows, authentication, ado.net, ssms

We have a windows application which allow users to connect to SQL using windows authentication.

The problem is the users of that application also have SSMS installed on their desktops so they can also connect to prod db using windows authentication.

Is there any way wherein we can restrict users from accessing prod db using windows authentication on SSMS but they should be able to access windows application from their local system using windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario correctly:

- You have an internal local database on Server 'A'
- You also have a production database on Server 'A'
- Using your custom windows application, users can only see the local non-production databases
- However, using SSMS users can see both production and local databases on Server 'A', and you would like only authorized users to be able to see production databases.

If this is the case, what you want to do in SSMS is revoke database view rights to all production databases unless the user is a sysadmin or owner of the database. Run the following on your server:

```
USE MASTER
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO PUBLIC
GO
```

**After you run the above statement, you will not be able to see any databases in SSMS unless you are a sysadmin or your login is the owner of a database.**

*Source:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2995/how-to-hide-sql-server-user-databases-in-sql-server-management-studio/*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could restrict access to your database objects by using application roles ... [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998.aspx): "You can use application roles to enable access to specific data to only those users who connect through a particular application."